# How to filter Magento Loaded Collection?

Tags: magento

What is the best practice to add filter to loaded collection in Magento? I want to hide items that are out of stocks and last updated date is not within last 30 days.

I try to create a function to hide the products in front end, then I realize it won’t affect the total item counts loaded in pager. I discovered that `_getProductCollection()` might the method I can use however I can’t add filter onto it.

I’m still new to Magento so any guidances are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter( 'status', '1' );
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
'created_at',
    array(
        'lteq'=>$last_day
    )
);    
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    'updated_at',
    array(
        'gteq'=>$first_day
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the out of stock products from the colection from admin settings under  `system->configuration->catalof->invemtory`
and set   `

> Display Out of Stock Products option to no

Hope this will help you

`

Comment: Thanks, but I need to filter by using two rules. Out of stock and last updated is not within 30 days.

Comment: for this you can check the  \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php to   and  _getProductCollection()  function in that  and you can add your filter there for created at

Answer (score 0):

you can add filter in _getProductCollection()  function in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php

```
from
> $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

to 

$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', 'your_value'));
```

`

Comment: you can also use filter value like  Shack Ro answer   ->addFieldToFilter(
'created_at',
    array(
        'lteq'=>$last_day
    )
);    
$this->_productCollection->addFieldToFilter(
    'updated_at',
    array(
        'gteq'=>$first_day
    )